# Check if an ActorRef is the user guardian

Tags: scala, akka

In an Akka `Actor`, I would like to send a message to my parent, but only if it is not the user guardian (i.e. only when the `Actor` is not a top level Actor).  What's the best way to check if an `Actor`'s parent is the User Guardian?

I can do something like:

```
if(context.parent.path.toString != "akka://system/user") { ... }
```

but is there a nicer way? I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
if(context.parent != context.system.userGuardian) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tricky, but it works:

```
if(context.parent != context.system.asInstanceOf[ExtendedActorSystem].guardian) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `==` comparison provided you have a reference to the user guardian.  This simple example shows that equality works correctly.  So I suppose you could resolve the user guardian somewhere and make it globally available if you wanted to do comparisons:

```
object RootGuardianTest extends App{
  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  system.actorOf(Props[ChildActor], "child")
}

trait RootComparison{ me:Actor =>

  def initCompare{
    val sel = context.system.actorSelection("/user")
    sel ! Identify()
  }

  def checkCompare:Receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(_, Some(ref)) =>      
      println(s"I am ${self.path}, and my parent is root: ${context.parent == ref}")    
  }
}

class ChildActor extends Actor with RootComparison{
  val child2 = context.actorOf(Props[Child2Actor], "child2")
  initCompare  
  def receive = checkCompare
}

class Child2Actor extends Actor with RootComparison{  
  initCompare  
  def receive = checkCompare
}
```

Me, I would just simply check the `name` portion of the path of the parent and see if it's 'user' like so:

```
val parentIsUser = context.parent.path.name == "user"
```